# emacs command to remove spaces until next parens

Tags: whitespace

I'm looking for a command that deletes automatically deletes spaces up to the next parens:

from:

```
(do |                 
            (do-something)
    true)
```

to:

```
(do |(do-something)
    true)
```

Comment: Hungry delete mode?

Comment: See the Elisp manual, node [User-Level Deletion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/User_002dLevel-Deletion.html). It presents and describes `fixup-whitespace`, `just-one-space`, `delete-horizontal-space`, `delete-indentation`, `delete-blank-lines`, and `delete-trailing-whitespace`, each of which might be relevant, depending on exactly what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is the command `just-one-space` which collapses all whitespace around the point down to a single space character. It works in any mode, not just paredit. By default it's bound to `M-SPC`, which can be hard to type since most window managers have a keyboard shortcut there that opens a menu. You can instead type `Esc SPC`.

Answer (score 7):

For deleting white spaces there are a few commands in Emacs. 
You can find it all in [**EmacsWiki DeletingWhiteSpaces**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace)

Here are two examples from the wiki:

**delete-horizontal-space**

`M-\` or `M-x delete-horizontal-space` will join two word, removing all the white spaces.

**delete-horizontal-space-forward**

Further down in the wiki page a function for deleting all white spaces forward (essentially what is asked in the example of the question)
You can add it to your configuration and bind a key to it.

```
(defun delete-horizontal-space-forward () ; adapted from `delete-horizontal-space'
  "*Delete all spaces and tabs after point."
  (interactive "*")
  (delete-region (point) (progn (skip-chars-forward " \t") (point))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, package https://github.com/jcpetkovich/shrink-whitespace.el is very convenient as it progressively reduces whitespace around the cursor. This is how I use it:

```
(use-package shrink-whitespace
  :bind ("M-SPC" . shrink-whitespace))
```